# How to use persian or arabic numbers in HTML

Tags: html, css

i'm working on a web site and i want to use persian/arabic numbers. but when i write the number, the numbers shown in english format. 
also i tried for this code :

```html
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
```

but it doesn't works for me. please show me a way.
its my web site :
http://follower.siblearn.ir
i wanna change the 2.500 and 5.000 to the persian/arabic format.

Comment: In this case, arabic numerals are not the same physical characters as 0,1,2...9. So you have to actually explicitly write arabic numerals like ٩ on your page for this to work. Of course, you could use client-side scripting to automatically replace 0,1,2...9 numerals with arabic numerals when their `lang` is `fa`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868380/converting-arabic-numerals-to-arabic-persian-numbers-in-html-file

Answer (score 1):

You should use Persian or Arabic font family like this:

```
body {  font-family: 'B Koodak',tahoma; }
```

before that, add some code like this to your html header:

```
<link href='http://www.fontonline.ir/css/BKoodakBold.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

remember you can use your favorite fonts from online or hosted files.

{   font-family: 'B Koodak'; }

on every tag or class you want to apply for numbers

[image: arabic numbers or persian numbers]